# How to change the WHM/cPanel account setting for "Use the nameservers specified at the Domain’s Registrar" after a cPanel account is created?

Tags: email, cpanel, nameserver, whm

I created a cPanel account through WHM, and I think I forgot to select the option "Use the nameservers specified at the Domain’s Registrar".

How can I change that option to start using remote nameservers now that I've created the cPanel account?

The problem is that a website for (say) mydomain.com in the account is sending messages to an email address info@mydomain.com and it's going to the wrong place because it's looking at the wrong nameservers.

Comment: Why don't you change the name servers at the Domain registrar panel? I think the nameserver and the corresponding DNS Zone you mentioned there should take effect irrespective of what you have mentioned in WHM. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: If it is just for email, you go into cpanel > email > routing > remote mail server

Comment: @Steve thanks. If you'd like to put that as an answer, I'll accept it. Kannan, the hosting account is sending email to the wrong MX server, as it's finding it's DNS settings locally rather than from the domain registrar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a cpanel server, you can change email routing (where your server routes email)  `cpanel` > `email` > `routing` > `remote mail server`

If MX is pointing to a remote server, one by-product of *not* doing this is that your server will attempt to deliver all emails generated on it, locally.  i.e. any contact forms, other users sending emails likely won't have them delivered.

Comment: Thanks! It's worth mentioning that in my most recent occurrence of this issue, the server was actually configured correctly, but the setting wasn't being applied. Rebooting the server fixed the issue. There had been some software updates outstanding for a while, which may or may not have made a difference.